# Simplify the difference of Beta functions $B\Big(\alpha, (k-4\alpha)/2\Big) - B\Big(k/2,(k-4\alpha)/2\Big) $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Can we simplify the difference of these two Beta functiona $$B\Big(\alpha, (k-4\alpha)/2\Big) - B\Big(k/2,(k-4\alpha)/2\Big) $$ where $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $k \in (2\alpha,4\alpha)$? In particular, I guess that their difference should be in the form of Beta function(s) with positive arguments instead of negative ones.

Answer (score 2):

The only simplication I can see is through the gamma function
$$B\left(a,\frac{1}{2} (k-4 a)\right)-B\left(\frac{k}{2},\frac{1}{2} (k-4 a)\right)=$$
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}-2 a\right) \left(\frac{\Gamma (a)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{k}{2}-a\right)}-\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (k-2
   a)}\right)$$